# RxJava: Subscription's unsubscribe() method isn't invoked

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

In code bellow I need to release some resources on unsubscription (where it logs "release").

```
   Observable first = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
                        subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> {
                            log(“release”);         
                        }));
                    }
                }).doOnUnsubscribe(() -> log(“first”));
   Observable second = Observable.create(…).doOnUnsubscribe(() -> log(“second”));
   Observable result = first.mergeWith(second).doOnUnsubscribe(() -> log(“result”));
   Subscription subscription = result.subscribe(…);
   //…
   subscription.unsubscribe();
```

But it logs only “result”. Looks like unsubscription is not propagated to merge’s child observables. So how to handle unsubscription inside of first observable’s Observable.OnSubscribe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time, calling `unsubscribe` has only effect on a live sequence and may not propagate if certain sequences have completed: the operators may not keep their sources around so they can avoid memory leaks. The main idea would be that operators release any resources they manage on termination just before or just after they call their downstream's `onError` or `onCompleted` methods, but this is somewhat inconsistent with 1.x.

If you want to make sure resources are releases, look at the `using` operator which will release your resource upon termination or unsubscription:

```
Observable.using(
    () -> "resource", 
    r -> Observable.just(r), 
    r -> System.out.println("Releasing " + r))
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```